# Error: The script threw an exception: Cannot create ActiveX component

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS script task that writes data from SQL table into an excel spreadsheet.  When I run this in debug, it runs successfully, but when I schedule a SQL job to run the package, I always receive this message: Error: The script threw an exception: Cannot create ActiveX component.
Also i have checked that my machine contain MS Excel also.

How to overcome this problem?
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: What are you using to read the Excel file?

Comment: In the SQL Agent's job step, on the Advanced tab have you selected "use 32 bit runtime"?